# Java - set the exact position of a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, position, layout-manager, jcomponent

I need help with setting the x and y position of a JLabel on a JPanel, **not** North,South,West,East.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why? that's the _sole_ responsibility of a LayoutManager, never-ever take it over manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a JPanel respect exact locations, you should set its layout to null.  Then, you can use `setLocation` on any JComponent to set its location within that JPanel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
label.setLocation(50, 20);
panel.add(label);
```

However, note that there are several downsides of absolute position (mentioned in comments below), and that you should utilize a LayoutManager to position your components.

Comment: technically correct, but a no-no-never (modulo odd corner cases) in Swing - use a LayoutManager instead

Comment: Though you never mentioned the downside of using the **Absolute Positioning** to the OP, another big mistake you committed in your snippet is not using the `setSize(...)`, for many a ***JComponents*** settings locations alone won't help much, you have to set the size too for the said **JComponent**

Comment: Correct (+1), but as kleopatra pointed out in a comment on the question, this shouldn't be done to begin with.  I answered the question which was asked, but I'll add that important note.